# Getting the result of an observable with pipe and map

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to setup an observable on a button and chain it to a service that returns an observable.

```
sydneyHttp$ = new Observable<string>();

this.sydneyHttp$ = fromEvent(this.sydneyServerButton, 'click')
      .pipe(
        map(() => this.streamService.getStream(1) )
      );
```

I get this error, the observable is wrapped in an observable:

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<string>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
```

I want to use it in a `flatMap` or `forkMap` with another click request.

Answer (score 1):

Change to mergeMap will solve the problem

```
sydneyHttp$ = new Observable<string>();

this.sydneyHttp$ = fromEvent(this.sydneyServerButton, 'click')
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.streamService.getStream(1) )
      );
```

Comment: Or possibly `switchMap`, I suspect that may be better in this situation but it can be hard to know.

Comment: @doe It sounds like you know that `map` and `flatMap` are different operations.  The same goes for `map` and `switchMap`/`mergeMap`.  If you call `map` and return an array for each item then you go from an array of items to an array of arrays.  If you call `flatMap` and return an array from each item then you still have an array of items.  Similarly, if you call `map` and return an observable then you go from an observable of items to an observable of observables.

Comment: map will return value as it is and will not unwrap/execute observable -this.streamService.getStream(1)